# How to find session cookie when not found in the developer tools?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, cookies

I want to automate requests on [a website](https://buff.market/) and when doing so, I need a session cookie in order to identify myself.

When checking the network tab, I can clearly see the session cookie, but when checking the Application tab, this cookie is not shown. After accessing this website with selenium and calling driver.get_cookies() with Python, I only get the cookies shown in the Application tab.

I need to do this with selenium because this way it's possible to login. Only using requests will not work.

I do not have many clues on how to get that cookie and have almost 0 experience in this field, hence my question.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I don't see why I need to add code. Driver.get_cookies() gets the cookies shown in the application tab in dev tools. Unfortunately, the session cookie is not present, so I want to know how I can get that cookie.